# PHPUnit: Calling methods inside dataprovider

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there anyway I can call a method within the dataprovider method? I tried doing it but the value passed from the dataProvider to the testAdd() method won't just pass. How do I do this?

PS: I do not want to call this from setUp() or setUpBeforeClass(), any way out?

```
<?php
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $expected, $someValue)
    {
        echo $someValue;
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $a + $b);
    }

    public function additionProvider()
    {
        $someValue = $this->doSomething();

        return array(
          array(0, 0, 0, $someValue),
          array(0, 1, 1, $someValue),
          array(1, 0, 1, $someValue),
          array(1, 1, 3, $someValue)
        );
    }

    protected function doSomething(){

      return 5 * 6;

    }
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I was not able to recreate your described problem with the code, the value 30 is echo'ed as expected using PHPUnit 3.7.28

Comment: Same for me. What is the problem?

Comment: The data provider is evaluated before the entire test suite runs, perhaps $this isn't read to doSomething at that point. e.g. setup won't have run yet.